# How to detect mute button event is triggered in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Neither I don't want to mute or unmutes iPhone nor I want to detect that it muted or unmuted, I just want to know, how can I detect mute button trigger event whether it is **on to off** or **off to on**?

Comment: AKAIK there is no API available for detecting the state of the mute button - lots of complaints on that front. You would have to resort to one of the many hacks which are available [for example](https://github.com/akramhussein/Mute)

Comment: Thanks @MadProgrammer :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no native iOS API to detect if the mute switch is enabled/disabled on a device.

The general principle to check if the device is muted is to play a short sound and detect the length it took to play. From this length, we can determine if it was muted or not. Check https://github.com/akramhussein/Mute or https://github.com/moshegottlieb/SoundSwitch

Comment: These Sound Switch shows deprecated method like: "Compiling IB documents for earlier than iOS 7 is no longer supported." Please tell is any another way was there.?